# What transfer technology is this: "SSL TCP/IP Real Time Connection"?

Tags: qt, ssl, curl, tcp, postman

I'm struggling with this question and did not found information in google, that's why I can't understand what are they talking about.

Please follow,

I was given a https address and a port, this address run a (as they called and I copy here) "TPC/IP using SSL. It's a "real time" protocol, that will give you real time data of the channels you subscribe"

So, I was given a document where they specify how to connect to some channels. It reads:

> This protocol is based on JSON format. The default port for this application is XXXXX, and the connection will be established using a SSL TCP-IP connection.
>
> Commands sent and received have the following format:
> command-id:[message-id[+]]:[channel]:[data]
> command-id = Valid commands are LOGIN, JOIN, LEAVE, PING , ACK , ERROR, REPLY, CMD , JSON (mandatory)
> [message-id] = Identification for message (optional on client)
> [channel] = channel name for command (optional on client)
> [data] = Json formated data  <-- (this data I copy an example below) (mandatory)
> All the commands use a \r\n (CR + LF) at the end of each line

```
Example of [data]  = {“user”:”XX”, , ”password”:”YYY”, app”:”ZZZ”, “app_ver”:”zzz” 
”protocol”:”xxx”,”protocol_ver”:”xxxx”}
```

Also, I provide an example of a complete command:

```
LOGIN:::{"user":"myname","password":"mypassword","app":"Manual Test", "app_ver":"1.0.0" , 
"protocol":"CustomProtocolABCD", "protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}
```

Here is what I tried:

Postman, forming the commands, message and data with Parameters, with Body, URL Encoding , everything. I only get "Error: Parse Error: Expected HTTP/" from postman

CURL, tried this also and it prompt me with this odd message "Expected HTTP 1.1 but response is HTTP 0.9". Ok I force this to --http0.9 and I finally get a response with a similar shape:

```
ERROR:1::{"reason":"Wrong number of parameters"}
```

Here is the question, How should I test it to send the right amount of parameters the server is expecting? I will provide here below mi CURL with credentials erased of course.

```
curl https://eu.xxxxxxxxxx.com:11001 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -k --verbose -d 'command-id:LOGIN' -d 'message-id:100' -d 'channel:' --http0.9 -d 'data:{"user":"XXXXXXX","password":"xxxxxxx","app":"ManualTest","app_ver":"1.0.0","protocol":"CustomProtocolABCD","protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}' -i
```

NOTE: The password contain a "%" symbol, I don't know if this is generating a problem in the encode but I'm very lost here.
Can someone help me pointing any documentation about this kind of communication? I'm really supposed to make an app consuming this information in a embedded device (Qt Creator) but I can't test the endpoint to receive initial json data and then program the app.

Any help is welcomed. Thanks and excuse my english if I made some mistake.

Thanks again

Comment: I don't know anything about this technology stack, butI  I would try getting the command to work from the shell command-line. Use `'single-quotes'` around the whole URL, but if the URL contains any `$envVars`, then replace the `$var`iable with the actual values. I you can see the simpilest implementation work, then you can continue trying to convert it into code. AND given that a `%` in the password ***could*** cause a problem, can you generate a new password (and keep trying) until you have a password without a `%``?  Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking now that's it's a custom protocol based on a websocket, but I'm still figuring out how to send these json commands. I'm currently trying to use a simple .Net console app to create a client socket and send this commands, no success at the time tho..

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not a valid JSON string.

This is the post data you are posting:

```
command-id:LOGIN&message-id:100&channel:&data:{"user":"XXXXXXX","password":"xxxxxxx","app":"ManualTest","app_ver":"1.0.0","protocol":"CustomProtocolABCD","protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}
```

This part of the post data is valid JSON:

```
'{"user":"XXXXXXX","password":"xxxxxxx","app":"ManualTest","app_ver":"1.0.0","protocol":"CustomProtocolABCD","protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}
```

But your header says it the whole body of the packet is `Content-Type: application/json`

Your actual content is mixed data where the one field `data` is JSON.
This is the non-JSON part:

```
command-id:LOGIN&message-id:100&channel:&data:
```

That looks like a mishmash of post data and JSON combined.

---

---

I can only guess but I would think data should look like this:

```
-d '{"command-id":"LOGIN","message-id":100,"channel":{"user":"XXXXXXX","password":"xxxxxxx","app":"ManualTest","app_ver":"1.0.0","protocol":"CustomProtocolABCD","protocol_ver":"1.0.0"}}'
```

Which translates to this:

```
obj(
  'command-id' => 'LOGIN',
  'message-id' => 100,
  'channel' => 
  obj(
    'user' => 'XXXXXXX',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
    'app' => 'ManualTest',
    'app_ver' => '1.0.0',
    'protocol' => 'CustomProtocolABCD',
    'protocol_ver' => '1.0.0',
  ),
)
```

But I am thinking curl is not a valid protocol for this TCP/IP packet.

You might be able to use curl if you send a body with no header.
Where the body is an SSL encoded packet.

What programming language[s] do you use?
I think I could do this in PHP with sockets and a little better documentation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time. I tried formatting the whole string to JSON format with no luck, also tried to change the Application-Type. I believe now that curl is not suitable to test it and I got to the conclusion that this is a socket server. I'm trying to use a socket client on C# .NET Console App to crack it with no luck at all. I'm starting to get frustrated. I will try to format a ASCII encoded message to sent with this socket I'm programming.

Comment: Do you know how this message should look like?
"{LOGIN:::{'user':'XXXXX','password':'XXXX','app':'Manual Test','app_ver':'1.0.0','protocol':'CustomProtocolABCD','protocol_ver':'1.0.0}}\r\n"

Comment: The part that confuses me the most is when I get that error response

ERROR:1::{"reason":"Wrong number of parameters"}

Which is indeed like the format my documentation says it will answer.. But I found no way to send the right amount of parameters..

Comment: Hi, I just realized I made a mistake when I edited some sensitive data, I'm really sorry for the inconveniences but I need to kindly ask you to edit your last comment to erase the address of the las section where you started to describe the package. I'm really sorry to bother you! I will give this another try tomorrow with a fresh head but I will pursue this idea where I need to write all the packet. Thanks again for your time, I'm glad to reach a experienced programmer like you are. It means a lot to me! Thanks!!

Comment: @boxitracio I deleted the comment.  All good now?

Comment: This is not easy stuff.  I will hang in here as long as I can be helpful.  If there is any documentation, that may help.

Comment: Hi! I've been pointed out in another forum and q couple of guys are saying that this could be a TCP socket and they also say that I can test it with                                      
 ```
openssl s_client -c connect host.com:11111
``` as a example of course. I will be testing this later in the morning and doing some research since I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use

```
openssl s_client -c connect host.com:11111
```

Additionally I had to use  \" instead of only " to overcome json encoding in my server.

It was indeed a SSL socket over TCP IP

In Qt I'm using QSslSocket class

Additional information for whoever needs it, this kind of sockets use to have a ping routine where you need to ping the server with a custom command to keep the connection alive.

In Qt I'm programming threads, and one of them will be used to ping the server once connection is established.